# Can I move a Windows 10 Pro product key from one PC to another?

Tags: windows-10, product-key

We have a few laptops, each with Windows 10 Home (All upgraded from Windows 8). One of these laptops was upgraded to Pro, purchased through the Windows Store. Now, that same laptop has had a different version of windows installed, and therefore, the key is no longer in use.

Can I use that key on a different laptop and upgrade it to Pro instead? and if so, how?

Comment: Assuming it's an OEM key, no.  That's associated with the hardware.  Move your retail Windows to the other machine.

Comment: If you upgraded a pre-installed Windows installation, then it will be an OEM version, which is tied to the laptop and cannot be moved. However, if the Pro licence you purchased was a retail version, this can be moved and you can reinstall W10 Home with the original licence. (Crossed with @fixer1234's comment.)

Comment: All of the laptops came with (an) OS pre-installed, and the advertisement on the Store suggests something similar - *"Windows 10 Pro can be installed and licensed to one PC - this one"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Pro version that you purchased from the Windows store was a retail version and not just an upgrade from the OEM version that came on your laptop, then yes, your key is transferable to another PC but it will invalidate the first PC. Do it by reinstalling Windows 10 on the new PC and using your purchased license.

However, if your key is an OEM key, then it cannot be transferred.